# I am PAKISTAN, but also ISTANBUL. Who am I?

Tags: logical-deduction, language, word-search

> I am PAKISTAN
>
> I am ISTANBUL
>
> I am KYRGYZSTAN

Who am I?

Comment: Is ' Kyrgyzstan ' written with small letters on purpose or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say:

> you're a [Stan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stan), as we can read the word in each country's name.
>  A stan is an obsessed fan, it s the blend of stalker + fan.

Answer (score 3):

I think

> You are a word [stan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-stan)(ستان), with meaning land or place, with Persian/Urdu origin.